# Negative base of log if working in $\mathbb{C}$?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, logarithms

Would a negative base of a logarithm be allowed if one were working in the field of complex numbers, $\mathbb{C}$?

Answer (score 3):

Yes: using the base change rule $\frac{\ln(c)}{\ln(-b)}=\log_{-b}(c)$ and $\ln(-n)=\ln(n)+\pi i$ so $\log_{-b}(x)=\frac{\ln(x)}{\ln(b)+\pi i}$

Answer (score 3):

Whether for the number or its base the same rule

For $(x,y ) >0$
$$\log_y (x)=\dfrac{\log x}{\log y}$$

for $ x>0, y <0$
$$\log_y (x)=\dfrac{\log x}{\log y+  (2k-1) \pi i}$$

for $ x<0, y <0$
$$\log_y (x)=\dfrac{\log x+  (2n-1) \pi i}{\log y+  (2k-1) \pi i}.$$

Comment: How do you know this? How can it be proved?

Comment: Basic log of a number consists of the log of its modulus with $i$ times its argument in the complex plane.

Comment: I see, thank you.